# Azure storage queue - geo redundancy

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, high-availability, azure-queues

Is there any option to maintain HA specifically on Azure storage queues/tables,  to do read as well as write to the queue on the secondary region if the primary goes down?

Is there any reference to do the programmatic failover switch?

For development & testing, how to simulate "primary" down situation?

If primary location is down, what kind/name of exception to except from Azure storage SDK to implement fail over to secondary?

Answer (score 0):

This is already enabled within Azure storage, you do not have to do anything further once you configure in the creation step.Azure Storage offers the following types of replication:

- Locally redundant storage (LRS)
- Zone-redundant storage (ZRS)
- Geo-redundant storage (GRS) or read-access geo-redundant storage (RA-GRS)
- Geo-zone-redundant storage (GZRS) or read-access geo-zone-redundant storage (RA-GZRS)

You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy#:%7E:text=Locally%20redundant%20storage%20(LRS)%20replicates,durability%20compared%20to%20other%20options.)

Comment: Lets say 'RA-GRS' enabled on my storage instance, will writes & reads continue to happen on secondary incase primary is down or ONLY it will take care of read since its name says "read-access geo-zone-redundant storage"?

Comment: it is supported only with ZRS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy

Comment: you can read more on the GRS asynchronous sync here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-disaster-recovery-guidance

Comment: The "RA" prefix shows that the secondary region can provide read-access at any time, not just after a failover has happened. But your applications need to be aware of how to read data from the secondary instance.